# Creating color boxes and tables

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tcolorbox

I want to create a LaTeX file which contains a box and a table like the picture below [image]

I try to do it but  my own file isn't like the picture. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Those are two totally different questions

Answer (score 3):

Quick hack:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{examplebox}[2][]{colframe=green,enhanced jigsaw, title={Example \thetcbcounter\ #2},coltitle={black},sharp corners,
  frame style={left color=orange,right color=black!20!white},
  #1}

\begin{document}


\chapter{Summary}

\begin{examplebox}{Computing the doubling time}
Computing the doubling time

\end{examplebox}


\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
  \textcolor{cyan}{Term, notation} & \textcolor{cyan}{Equations} \tabularnewline
  \toprule
  1. Exponential function & the equation  \tabularnewline
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{} \tabularnewline

  2. The number & Compute \tabularnewline
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I anticipated you with this `;-)` +1.

Comment: @HarishKumar: The Dark side of the force is strong in you :-P

Comment: May be I am made up of more dark matter `;-)`. We have two common things though. 1. like `tcolorbox` and 2. not use `KOMA` `:-)`

Comment: Christian Hupfer, I see your box isn't like as the box in the picture.

Comment: @ablhope: I never said it would be the same.